Laravel 11 route passes empty object to edit form
I'm trying to populate an edit form when accessed from a list... The object's in the database, loads through laravel, and can be outputted into the list in Laravel, but when I click the edit link, as described below, there's no data in the object for the edit form. The id (primary key) appears correct, and the object class is correct, but laravel is not loading the data into the object.
Hopefully the details below will explain better.
I have an eloquent model called School in a laravel 11 livewire 3 jetstream app, it has a primary key "id" in a mariadb database.
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class School extends Model{

    use HasFactory;

    public $table = "school";

    protected $fillable = [
        "name",
        "address1",
        "address2",
        "town",
        "city",
        "postcode",
    ];
}

This model loads successfully as a list in an index blade file, via the SchoolController.php file, using this code...
public function index(){
    if(School::all() != null){
        $schools = School::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
    }
    return view('schools.index',['schools'=>$schools]);
}

The school/index.blade.php looks like this...
<x-app-layout>
    <div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-[1fr_auto] m-4">
            @foreach($schools as $school)
                <div class="p-4 w-full">{{ $school->name }}
                </div>
                <div class="p-4">
                    <a href="{{ route("schools.show", $school) }}">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>

This all loads, and works fine...
See listing of school objects with edit button
clicking the Edit link, takes me to the schools/show.blade.php view, such as:
schools/show/2

Where 2 is the School object with id 2, as per the database.
The route is this:
Route::get('/schools/{id}',[SchoolController::class,'show'])->name('schools.show');

It loads through the controller:
public function show(School $school)
{
    return view('schools.show', ['school'=>$school]);
}

Which loads fine, but the $school object arriving at this function is empty, so no data can be populated into the form...
Details of school object are not available to be loaded into this form
The show.blade.php looks like this...
<x-app-layout>
    <form action="{ { route('schools.update') } }" method="POST" class="school">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="maw-7xl mauto sm:p6 lg:p8">
                <slot name="header">
                     <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">{{ $school->name }}</h2>
                </slot>
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg p-5">
                    <!-- Name -->
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4"><x-label for="name" value="{{ __('School Name') }}" />
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model="school.name" required autocomplete="name" />
                    <x-input-error for="name" class="mt-2" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</x-app-layout>

Outputting the $school object from the Controller in the show(School $school) function, using print_r($school); gives this...

App\Models\School Object ( [connection:protected] => [table] => school [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [preventsLazyLoading] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => [wasRecentlyCreated] => [escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( ) [original:protected] => Array ( ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [attributeCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [timestamps] => 1 [usesUniqueIds] => [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => address1 [2] => address2 [3] => town [4] => city [5] => postcode ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) ) 1

...and so, an un-populated edit form.
If anyone can spot what is doubtless a silly error, or a misunderstanding of how Laravel works, or point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Instead of Route::get('/schools/{id}', try Route::get('/schools/{school}'. I think the argument needs to match, so the way you have it now, you'd have to do show(int $id), and manually do School::find($id). If you change it to /{school}, then School $school should work. Also, sidenote, if(School::all() != null) { will never evaluate to false; ::all() returns a Collection, which even if empty is not null. You can do if (!School::all()->isEmpty()) { ... }, or simply remove this if() statement completely.

Also 1 more note, to get more visibility on your question, use the laravel and php tags; more people watch those instead of laravel-{version}, livewire-{version}, etc.

That worked perfectly. Thank you, Tim Lewis. I simply changed /schools/{id} to /schools/{school} in the Route::get statement as you suggested, and hey presto!

I had a very similar problem, but with a resource route. Turns out, the parameter name in the controller method must be exactly the same as the parameter name in the route. So, if the show route points to, e.g. myobjects/{myobject}, the show(Myobject $myobject) method parameter in the controller MUST be named $myobject, and not $myobjectData or something else.
Found that answer here: https://laraveldaily.com/post/laravel-route-model-binding-returns-null-empty-object
